# How can i simulate tcp simultaneous open and close condition?

Tags: network-programming, tcp, simultaneous

I am learning TCP IP protocol. I want to see simultaneous open, close, half open/close, etc conditions in practice. I have created simple TCP server and client program. How can I simulate simultaneous open/close, half open/close conditions? Like giving sleep in between, control-c, etc. I am using 'netstat' to see the TCP packets. Can it be simulated in same machine (both server and client will be running)?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this question in SuperUser site, as SO is for programming based questions.

Comment: @jpou You can't answer this question *without* programming.

Answer (score 0):

I only simulated tcp simultaneous close:

server.py:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('127.0.0.5', 10000)
#print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    #print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    connection.close()
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import sys
import Queue, threading, logging

def do_client():
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
    server_address = ('127.0.0.5', 10000)
    #print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
    sock.connect(server_address)
    sock.close()

class WorkManager(object):
    def __init__(self, work_num=100,thread_num=10):
        self.work_queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.threads = []
        self.__init_work_queue(work_num)
        self.__init_thread_pool(thread_num)

    def __init_thread_pool(self,thread_num):
        for i in range(thread_num):
            self.threads.append(Work(self.work_queue))

    def __init_work_queue(self, work_num):
        for i in range(work_num):
            self.add_job(do_job, i)

    def add_job(self, func, args):
        self.work_queue.put((func, args))

    def check_queue(self):
        return self.work_queue.qsize()

    def wait_allcomplete(self):
        for item in self.threads:
            if item.isAlive():item.join()

class Work(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, work_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.work_queue = work_queue
        self.start()
    def run(self):

        while True:
            try:
                do, args = self.work_queue.get(block=False)
                #print do, args
                do(args)
                self.work_queue.task_done()
            except Exception,e:
                print str(e)
                break

def do_job(args):
    #print args
    do_client()
    #print threading.current_thread(), args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_manager =  WorkManager(100, 10)
    work_manager.wait_allcomplete()
```

I tested on winodws7, found tcp simultaneous close like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rr7N.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

To get full control over TCP session setup, etc, one way is to craft your own TCP/IP packets and send using a raw socket. This is a bit of work, but you will really have to learn exactly how TCP/IP packets are constructed that way so this can be a good learning experience.

Comment: This is neither necessary nor sufficent.

Comment: Please don't add commentary on your answer in your answer. Ask @EJP to elaborate using comments. You also can't see who voted on your post.

Comment: Sorry, learning, I appreciate the instructions. @EJP, can you please elaborate why you don't believe it is a way forward to craft packets and use raw sockets to study TCP behavior (e.g. to send a single TCP SYN package). I've done exactly that and learned a lot from it.